# Woocommerce Products assigned to a post, (using the ACF Relationship field) to show listed in that certain post

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a ACF Relationship field that appears inside woocommerce product.  With that Relationship field, I assign normal Posts to products.

EDIT: switched to **ACF Relationship field**

*What I am trying to do:*
Now when viewing a Post (not the product!) in the frontend, I try to show all product titles from the products to which the post is assigned to.

Its no problem to show the post inside the product detail page, using the ACF queries. But we need it the other way round. Is there way to query that in the post single template. Check to which products this post is assigned and show the titles?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**

Inside the single-post.php Template run a subquery:

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'   => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,  // -1 will get all the product. Specify positive integer     value to get the number given number of product
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
    array(
        'key'     =>  'RELATIONSHIP_FIELD_SLUG',
        'value'   =>  $post_id,
        'compare' =>  'LIKE',
    ),
)
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    // Show the title
    the_title();

endwhile;
} else {
    echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```